# Searching items from an array in a string in Javascipt?

Tags: javascript

say I have a set of string from which I have to search within a string that it contains any element or not.

```js
var value = "01,05,04,02,00";
var temp = ["00", "01", "02", "03"];
```

I want to search existence of any item from  temp in value, if any of the items from temp found in value, it should return true else false. what I am trying to do is opposite of searching a string in an array.
How to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: `var temp="00","01","02","03";` is not valid Javascript. Did you mean `var temp=["00","01","02","03"];`?

Comment: @FelipeZavan , no. I am searching in a string, not in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Javascript you would use `Array.prototype.some` along with `Array.prototype.includes` for this:

```js
const value = "01,05,04,02,00", arr = ["00", "01", "02", "03"];
let arrayItemInString = arr.some(el => value.split(',').includes(el));
console.log(arrayItemInString);
```

If instead you want to check if **all** array values are included in your string, use `Array.prototype.every`:

```js
const value = "01,05,04,02,00", arr = ["00", "01", "02", "03"];
let arrayItemsInString = arr.every(el => value.split(',').includes(el));
console.log(arrayItemsInString);
```

Please note that for both solutions to work you need to convert your String to an array as well. The examples do this using `value.split(',')`.

You could also use `String.prototype.includes`, but that would be alot less reliable as an array value of `01` would also be included in this string: `010`:

```js
const value = "010", arr = ["00", "01", "02", "03"];
let arrayItemInString = arr.some(el => value.includes(el));
console.log(arrayItemInString);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this solution

```
function search(){
    var value= "01,05,04,02,00";
    var temp=["00","01","02","03"];
    for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        if(value.indexOf(temp[i])!==-1)
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
        return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value= "01,05,04,02,00";
var temp=["00","01","02","03"];

const matchedItems = !!value.split(',').filter(item => temp.includes(item)).length
```

If value is an array like temp:

```
const matchedItems = !!value.filter(item => temp.includes(item)).length
```